# C# notify a form that the text in a custom text box (precompiled) has changed

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, richtextbox

I made a custom text box derived from RichTextBox (Win Forms, .Net 2.0):

```
public partial class MyTextBox : RichTextBox {
```

I want to reuse this custom text box in several projects, so I'll compile it and reference it as a dll. In one of my projects, I have a form which uses this custom text box. Whenever the text in the custom text box has changed, I want to notify the parent form so that it can signal the user that the text has changed.

```
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        // notify the parent form somehow that text has changed
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
```

The only way I can think of to do this is to add a function to the parent form that reacts to the text change, pass a reference to this function to the custom text box (as a delegate?) and trigger it from within OnTextChanged (I'm not sure if delegates work in .Net 2.0). Are there better ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of you want already implemented in the `.NET`. `RichTextBox` has public event `TextChanged` which is inherited by your class and you can subscribe to this event in your form.

```
public class MyForm
{
    private MyTextBox _textBox;
    ....

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _textBox = new MyTextBox();
        _textBox.TextChanged += (s, e) => {...};
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Thanks.